# How to make new column through foreach loop in html table

Tags: magento2, php, html

I want to make one column with three rows after that second and third column should be made. With this code, only one column is being created.

```
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $a => $v) {

    if(empty($a)){
        continue;
    }
    $table .= "<td style='font-weight: 600;width: 9%;'>$a</td><td style='width: 10%;'>$v</td>";
    //^           ^ double quotes for the variables
    if(($i+0) % 1 == 0)
        $table .= "</tr><tr>";
    $i++;


}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Anees, could you add screen shot, what you need ?

Comment: I want above two coloumns into four columns having 3 rows each.